# How to pause youtube video on slide change?

Tags: javascript, video, youtube, carousel, swiper.js

I am trying to pause a youtube video when a slide changes using [swiper from iDangerous](https://idangero.us/swiper/api/#events)

I have the youtube video urls ending with `enablejsapi=1` and here is some code, the important part being `slideChange`:

```
var swiper_video = new Swiper('.swiper-video', {

    loop: true,
    autoplay: false,
    pagination: {
      el: '.swiper-pagination',
    },
    navigation: {
      nextEl: '.swiper-button-next.video-swiper',
      prevEl: '.swiper-button-prev.video-swiper',
    },
    slideChange: function (el) {
      console.log('1');
      $('.swiper-slide').each(function () {
        var youtubePlayer = $(this).find('iframe').get(0);
        if (youtubePlayer) {
          youtubePlayer.contentWindow.postMessage('{"event":"command","func":"pauseVideo","args":""}', '*');
        }
      });
    },
  });
```

Can't seem to get the event to even fire, but I think the rest of the code should work.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your event looks like it is declared incorrectly, should be inside `on:{}`, something like:

```
var swiper_video = new Swiper('.swiper-video', {
  on: {
    slideChange: function () {
      console.log('Hello World') 
    },
  }
});
```

So with your full code:

```
var swiper_video = new Swiper('.swiper-video', {
  loop: true,
  autoplay: false,
  pagination: {
    el: '.swiper-pagination',
  },
  navigation: {
    nextEl: '.swiper-button-next.video-swiper',
    prevEl: '.swiper-button-prev.video-swiper',
  },
  on: {
    slideChange: function (el) {
      console.log('1');
      $('.swiper-slide').each(function () {
        var youtubePlayer = $(this).find('iframe').get(0);
        if (youtubePlayer) {
            youtubePlayer.contentWindow.postMessage('{"event":"command","func":"pauseVideo","args":""}', '*');
        }
      });
    },
  },
});
```

Check out the [API docs for events here](https://idangero.us/swiper/api/#events), or a [working example here](https://jsfiddle.net/y38wo762/1/)